# can i simplify the use of postgres_fdw if the foreign db is in the same server

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw, pg-hba.conf

my server has several databases. I want to be able to read db1 from queries in db2. I know I can use postgres_fdw to do it but that has a couple of drawbacks. The main one is that I have to pass credentials around, worry over when I change passwords etc.

Answer (score 3):

so you set up server, user mapping and create tables:

```
t=# create server l foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw options (host 'localhost', dbname 't');
CREATE SERVER
t=# create user mapping FOR postgres SERVER l;
CREATE USER MAPPING
t=# create table lt(i serial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into lt default values;
INSERT 0 1
t=# create foreign table ft (i int) server l options(table_name 'lt') ;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
t=# select * from ft;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

now If I add md5 to hba before trust local default connection, I get:

```
t=# select * from ft;
ERROR:  could not connect to server "l"
DETAIL:  fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

and revert:

```
t=# \! sed -i '43s/host/#host/' /pg/d10/pg_hba.conf
t=# select pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf
----------------
 t
(1 row)

t=# select * from ft;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

while the line is:

```
t=# \! sed '43,43!d' /pg/d10/pg_hba.conf
#host   all     postgres    127.0.0.1/32        md5
```

So my point is: If you have local databases, you by default don't need to manipulate passwords, as you have peer or trust for localhost...

**update**
so in order to work on localhost without a password for some user you need line, like:

```
host    fdw_db      postgres    127.0.0.1/32        trust
```

to go before the line like:

```
host    all     all 127.0.0.1/32        md5
```

or any other line that restricts or rejects connections

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

> Since the pg_hba.conf records are examined sequentially for each
>   connection attempt, the order of the records is significant.
>   Typically, earlier records will have tight connection match parameters
>   and weaker authentication methods, while later records will have
>   looser match parameters and stronger authentication methods. For
>   example, one might wish to use trust authentication for local TCP/IP
>   connections but require a password for remote TCP/IP connections. In
>   this case a record specifying trust authentication for connections
>   from 127.0.0.1 would appear before a record specifying password
>   authentication for a wider range of allowed client IP addresses.

Comment: it seems to be that you are saying I need to add / change something in my hba.conf file. But its not very clear - you show various sed commands etc. Can you just say, "change x in your config to say y"

Comment: line 43 in my config file says `# directly connected to.` So this is not helpful at all

Comment: please please please tell me what line I need in the config

Comment: ty - i did not have a line like that anywhere in my 9.6 default config

Comment: as far as i can see I have done what you say 'DETAIL:  FATAL:  role "SYSTEM" does not exist' when select remote table

Comment: oh... windows?.. try this line as first:`host    all      all    127.0.0.1/32        trust` - if it works, you can try picking up more strict values ater

Comment: i did that - it used to say 'no password supplied' now it complains about SYSTEM role

Comment: Im not sure about windows - but I assume SYSTEM would be like peer method here?..